# Cannot click on login button in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to automate login to this [website.](https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F) While Python adds username and password, it couldn't click on login button "Inloggen". I do not get any error but it does not click on login button.

here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = "https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F"
username = "cosmos"
password = "12345"

driver.get(url)

driver.get('https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
"//span[text()='Gebruikersnaam']//following::div[1]//input"))).send_keys("cosmos")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
"//span[text()='Wachtwoord']//following::div[1]//input"))).send_keys("12345")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Wachtwoord']//following::div[1]//input").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css selector instead of xpath. It's work for me

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#app > div.application--wrap > div.tw-flex.tw-w-full.tw-pr-8 > div > div > div > div > div > section > form > footer > div.form__footer-bottom.form__footer-bottom--login > div > button").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that works pretty good with xpath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = "https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F"
username = "cosmos"
password = "12345"

driver.get(url)

driver.get('https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
"//span[text()='Gebruikersnaam']//following::div[1]//input"))).send_keys("cosmos")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
"//span[text()='Wachtwoord']//following::div[1]//input"))).send_keys("12345")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/section/form/footer/div[2]/div/button").click()
```

Whether you're using Firefox or chrome, You can use inspect the element and right-click on your desired element and select `copy > copy xpath`

You can use copy CSS selectors as well:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".form__footer-bottom > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check the selector for button first, seems like you are trying to click onto `password` input instead of `button`.

As `@Sumsul Islam` said, there is no need to use `xpath` in this case, each element is accessible by css selectors just fine.

But also it's quite enough to use this selectors instead of full `css` path:

```
//login
input[type="text"]

//password
input[type="password"]

//button
.form__footer button
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `locator`.

**Xpath:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Inloggen')]"))).click()
```

**Css Selector:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class='mi-button__Container']> .button--normal.icon.button--normal-secondary.button--mi"))).click()
```